# escaping regular expression for password

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to test if the input password contains at least 8 characters and at least one digit and at least one letter.
I think that my problem is in escaping the regular expression.

```
            function validatePassword(password){

                    var passwordReg = new RegExp(^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$);

                    var valid = passwordReg.test(password.trim());

                    if(!valid) {
                            return false;
                    } else {
                            return true;
                    }
            }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: add quotes in `RegExp` parameter. `new RegExp("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare a regex literal:

```
function passwordIsValid(password) {
   return /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$/.test(password);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your regex with the forward slash:

```
new RegExp(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})$/)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/seminull/d4nhLm1d/